# struts 2 external stylesheet link

Tags: struts2

Hi how can i include an external style sheet link in to my Struts2 jsp page.

here is my code.

```
  <link href="css/style_inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using an absolute path. But what's the actual question? Are you saying this isn't working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style_inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` points to your application root.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Does not matter what context path the application is running with. Resources loaded with this approach will always work.

Answer (score 3):

Using `<s:url>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<s:url value="/css/style.css"/>">
```

Comment: Namespaces might be a problem with this approach - if using this, make sure to utilize the `namespace` attribute.

Comment: @demaniak: Namespaces are not a problem with this approach. Note this is `value` attribute of `<s:url>` tag and path begins with a `/`.

Comment: Ok, I might be doing something weird: using `<s:include` to pull in common head chunk. If I don't provide the `namespace` attrib, and I'm in some 'sub' namespace, I get the sub namespace pre-pended to the resulting URL. Even when starting with "/". But, as stated, I might be doing it in Not The 100% Correct Way (TM). Either case, using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css` solved my issues like a boss.

Answer (score 0):

Like you did. And with your code you need to find the .css file under your webapp directory, on a directory named "css".

Comment: Not necessarily; depending on how the fragment is used, a relative path may not resolve to the root level of web content.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same  issue now i got fixed, see my code

```
<link href="../css/style_inner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Not necessarily; depending on how the fragment is used, a relative path may not resolve to the root level of web content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/alert-messages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```